# SSRS OracleClient Error in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, system.data.oracleclient

I've searched around for an answer to this, but have thus far been unsuccessful finding something that works for me.

I am attempting to connect to an Oracle database in an SSRS report within VS2008, but always get the following error:

> System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

I'm guessing it is a configuration issue (I have 11g client stuff installed on my system), but I can't seem to figure it out.  The connection string also appears to be correct, as it works correctly on other machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps someone in the future, I will answer it here instead of deleting the question.

I had multiple versions of Oracle installed on this PC, some added by another user (it's a work laptop that I inherited and no control of what was installed previously).

I had to uninstall and reinstall the Oracle client (I chose the 11g R2 Client).  At that point, everything appears to have been cleaned up, and I can run SSRS inside VS2008.